# Will "Reset decompiler information"+"All caches" invalidate functions marked as decompiled?

Tags: hexrays

In his answer to a question, Rolf pointed me to the <kbd>Edit</kbd> -> <kbd>Other</kbd> -> <kbd>Reset decompiler information</kbd> functionality, suggesting that "All caches" will force the decompiler to pick up *immediately* on changes I made to the disassembly.

[image: Reset decompiler information dialog]

This sounds like a sensible idea. However, he cautions that the resetting will also mean that the decompiler has more work to do on subsequent decompilations. Makes sense.

**Now the question I have is:** when I use the <kbd>Mark as decompiled</kbd> menu item on the pseudo code and only *then* use the <kbd>Reset decompiler information</kbd> functionality, will the functions marked decompiled be exempt from the clearing of caches?

[image: Mark as decompiled menu item]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not exempt from the caches being cleared; marking something as decompiled simply changes the color of the function in the `func_t`, and does not affect the caches in any way. However, this is not a big deal. The "caches" referred to by that menu item simply mean the saved `cfunc_t` and `mba_t` data structures for that function, which Hex-Rays uses to accelerate subsequent decompilations of functions you've already looked at. You won't lose any annotations (names, comments, types, having marked a function as decompiled, etc.) by clearing the caches. I clear the caches multiple times a day on databases that are important to me; don't worry about losing your work. If you're really paranoid, save your database or create a snapshot first before giving it a try; you'll see that you don't lose any of your work.

The only negative effect is the slowdown on re-decompiling unrelated functions that you otherwise have no interest in clearing the cache entries for. If you don't like that slowdown, an IDAPython one-liner `ida_hexrays.mark_cfunc_dirty(funcEa)` will clear the `cfunc_t` cache entry for the function at address `funcEa` (though I'm not sure if it will also purge the `mba_t` cache entry, which is likely necessary to trigger the changes stemming from the disassembly listing).